# GPUImageMovie: how to show the first frame of the video after playback is completed?

Tags: ios, swift, video, gpuimage

Here's how I'm setting the playback:

```
movie = GPUImageMovie(url: url)
movie.playAtActualSpeed = true
movie.delegate = self
movie.addTarget(self)
movie.startProcessing()
```

After the playback is completed, `GPUImageView` shows the last frame of the video file. How to change it to the first frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `AVPlayerItem` and let `AVPlayer` to handle playback for us:

```
func configure(url: URL) {
    // player is AVPlayer instance declated as property
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)

    movie = GPUImageMovie(playerItem: playerItem)
    movie.playAtActualSpeed = true
    movie.addTarget(self)
    movie.startProcessing()
}

func playerDidFinishPlaying(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard player.currentItem == notification.object as? AVPlayerItem else { return }
    player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
}
```